# The Probability of Landing Inside an Infinitesimal Region with Volume (Area?) $\delta x$ Is Given by $p(x) \delta x$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, terminology, density-function

My textbook says the following when discussing continuous random variables and probability density functions:

> A probability density function $p(x)$ does not give the probability of a specific state directly; instead the probability of landing inside an infinitesimal region with volume $\delta x$ is given by $p(x) \delta x$.

My understanding is that, in the univariate case, it should be "area" not "volume, right? Wouldn't it only be "volume" in the multivariate case?

Comment: The terms are often used loosely. The term 'measure' is less dimension specific but is less tangible.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok, but *technically* I'm correct, right? If we're being pedantic.

Comment: Is $\delta x$ an area or a volume?

Comment: @copper.hat Neither? It's just the change in $x$. It would have to be multiplied by height to be an area, as is the case with Riemann sums/integrals.

Comment: If you were talking about an area, such as the chance that a dart hits an area around the bulls eye then I would use area, if you are talking about a volume, such as the chances of finding a bee inside your car, then I would use volume. In other cases, I would use measure or volume but that is me.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If "univariate" means that $x$ is a real number, then I think that "length" would make more sense than "area".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's technically correct to call it a volume (this term is not restricted to three- or even multi-dimensional space in mathematics), judging from [the context](https://books.google.de/books?id=Np9SDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22instead%20the%20probability%20of%20landing%20inside%20an%20infinitesimal%20region%20with%20volume%22&source=bl&ots=kRKdrGy40Y&sig=vSAMtxux2HyNT1sbRHsxsVuejl8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihgczq3qLcAhWLZlAKHSTQCuwQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22instead%20the%20probability%20of%20landing%20inside%20an%20infinitesimal%20region%20with%20volume%22&f=false) it's indeed a bad choice of terminology here, since the entire surrounding text treats $x$ as a univariate variable and uses two separate variables $x$ and $y$ in all two-dimensional examples. If $x$ were known to be univariate, “length” or “measure” would be a much more usual choice of term; “volume” would still be technically correct but unnecessarily confusing.  Using “volume” here seems like a half-hearted attempt to generalize; while the generalization is in order, it would have required either more explanation or a notation that distinguishes the implied multivariate from the surrounding univariates.